# I can't use this.props.navigation.navigate in version 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import News from './src/screens/News';
import Photos from './src/screens/Photos'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="News" >
        <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={News}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Photos" component={Photos} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I try to call in my header using this.props.navigation.openDrawer()

```
<View style={style.iconHeader}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
    <Feather name='menu' size={36} color='black' />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Returns the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer()')

Comment: Can you log the value of `this.props` inside your `onPress` ? and also are you using functional or class based component?

Comment: component based class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using v5 you can use DrawerActions from @react-navigation/native

```
import { useNavigation, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

And do it like this:

```
    const navigation = useNavigation();
      return (
      <View style={style.iconHeader}>
      <TouchableOpacity   onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
        }}>
        <Feather name='menu' size={36} color='black' />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even if it's in the class-based component?

Comment: Yes it will even work in the class based component, include the above thing in render()

Comment: I received the following error: Can't find variable: useNavigation, this is the code. https://github.com/RUANDUARTE03/AppFrontSousa

Comment: import { useNavigation, DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native'; try this once